# How to link a header file from the Visual Studio Command Prompt?

Tags: c, visual-studio, header

I am trying to compile and link the following source and the header file

### source.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "source.h"

int main(void)
{
    three_lines();

    return 0;
}
```

### source.h

```
 void three_lines(void);
```

using the command as shown below.

```
 cl /W4 /EHsc source.c /link source.h
```

but I get the following error.

```
 Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26433 for x86
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 source.c
 Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.14.26433.0
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 /out:source.exe
 source.h
 source.obj
 source.h : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x61
```

Could someone please guide me on how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in VS, but normally you never link header files, since they should contain no definitions if properly written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/link` option if for linking object files together.  What you have is a header file.  This doesn't get linked but instead gets **included**.  This happens automatically by the preprocessor when you `#include "source.h"`.

Get rid of the `/link` option and it should compile.

Comment: @AlokY Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Now it compiles even with the /link option! I don't know what's going on..